# Optional line break in HTML

Tags: html, word-wrap

`<br>` always breaks the line in a particular location. Is there a way to hint to the browser that a particular location is better for a line break than another?

Consider the following text when center aligned:

```
"Connect with UTS Library for one-click sign
in."
```

I'd like the browser to try to keep the lines more even

Comment: with css property 'word-break' is better solution.

Comment: @Suleman, `word-break` is a solution (or, usually, a non-solution) to a completely different problem: how to break words.

Comment: The question is not about *optional* line break (which is what `<wbr>` is for, more or less) but about *preferred* line breaks. And it really boils down to *preventing* line breaks that are no preferred (allowed).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First thing that immediately comes to mind is `&nbsp;` which makes sense in your specific use case with the phrase "sign in":

```
"Connect with UTS Library for one-click sign&nbsp;in."
```

This prevents "sign" and "in" from being split by a line break, effectively treating it as a single word in that sense. The browser will choose the next best place to wrap the text, which would be the space between "one-click" and "sign".

Beyond strategic placements of `&nbsp;`, I don't think HTML offers any viable solutions for dealing with widows and orphans in text.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `&#160;` non-breaking space

```
Connect with UTS Library for one-click sign&#160;in.
```